# Error input property undefined

Tags: angular, typescript

the following error appears on the console several times but I do not know what causes it. It works but the error keeps appearing on the console

```
    UserComponent.html:43 ERROR CONTEXT DebugContext_
View_UserComponent_0 @ UserComponent.html:43
UserComponent.html:43 ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'email' of undefined
    at Object.eval [as updateDirectives] (UserComponent.html:43)
    at Object.debugUpdateDirectives [as updateDirectives] (core.js:14648)
    at checkAndUpdateView (core.js:13795)
    at callViewAction (core.js:14146)
    at execComponentViewsAction (core.js:14078)
    at checkAndUpdateView (core.js:13801)
    at callViewAction (core.js:14146)
    at execEmbeddedViewsAction (core.js:14104)
    at checkAndUpdateView (core.js:13796)
    at callViewAction (core.js:14146)
    at execComponentViewsAction (core.js:14078)
    at checkAndUpdateView (core.js:13801)
    at callWithDebugContext (core.js:15049)
    at Object.debugCheckAndUpdateView [as checkAndUpdateView] (core.js:14586)
    at ViewRef_.webpackJsonp.../../../core/esm5/core.js.ViewRef_.detectChanges (core.js:11570)
```

Line accused in error

```
<input type="email" class="form-control border-input" placeholder="Email..."  name="inputEmail" [ngModel]="userEdit.email" [required]="true" [email]="true" #email="ngModel">
```

Thank you for any help

Comment: Is `userEdit` undefined?

Comment: No it gets db information every time and the input shows the information without problems

Comment: Try `[ngModel]="userEdit?.email"`.

Comment: This worked but why?

Comment: it works because initially `userEdit` is `undefined`. You can also solve this in case you do not have a nested object to just initialize `userEdit = {}` then it's not trying to read property email of `undefined`, instead it will be an empty object. Safe navigation operator works here because it safeguards `undefined`/`null` values.